# Integrations, how i can solve this?

Tags: integration

I have this integrals to solve:

$ \int \frac{x^2 - 2x + 2}{{x^2 - 1}}dx$

$ \int xe^{3x^2}\,dx$

The first it's difficult and the second it's impossibile! How i can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first integral is pretty easy
$$\int\frac{x^2 - 2x + 2}{{x^2 - 1}}dx=\int\frac{(x^2-1) - 2x + 3}{{x^2 - 1}}dx=x-\int\frac{ 2x }{{x^2 - 1}}dx+\int\frac{ 2}{{x^2 - 1}}dx\\
=x-\ln(|x^2-1|)+\ln\left(\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|\right)+C$$

The second isn't impossible

$$\int xe^{3x^2}\,dx=\frac16\int 6xe^{3x^2}\,dx=\frac16e^{3x^2}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
For the first one you have: $x^2-2x+2=x^2-2x+1+1=(x-1)^2+1$ and than you can divide into to integrals which can be solved easy.

For the second one you have: $xdx=\frac{1}{2}d(x^2)=\frac{1}{6}d(3x^2)$ and then replace $3x^2=t$.

Answer (score 0):

Use Substitution $3x^2$=t in second one